# Rails scope: association is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations

In my Rails app, projects can have videos.  I want to create a scope for the Project to grab projects that **do not** have a video associated with it.  How do I do this?

Here are my model associations

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :video
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
end
```

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails scope to check if association does NOT exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355002/rails-scope-to-check-if-association-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 6):

Just faced this right now, and this has worked for me:

```
Project.includes(:video).where(videos: { id: nil })
```

The trick is to use the singular in `includes` and the plural in `where`

Answer (score 3):

building off of messanjah's answer, the way you would turn that into a scope is the following:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :video
  scope :videoless, -> { left_joins(:videos).where("videos.id IS NULL") }
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a LEFT join and select out rows where the joined id is null.

```
Project.joins("LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.project_id = projects.id").
  where("videos.id IS NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this should work: `Project.where.not(id: Video.select(:project_id).uniq)`. Maybe you don't need `uniq` if a project has one unique video.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this 
Project.joins(:video).where('videos.id IS NULL')

Comment: This will always return an empty set because joins(:video) uses an INNER join on videos.id, so "videos.id IS NULL" will not match any records.