# Rails scope by absence of has_one polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, default-scope

I have records that, instead of being deleted, are invalidated by creating an entry in a polymorphic record_invalidations table.

The setup looks like this:

```
class RecordInvalidation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :archivable, polymorphic: true
end


class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :invalidation, class_name: "RecordInvalidation", as: :archivable

  def self.default_scope
    where(invalidation: nil)
  end
end
```

(There are multiple record classes, hence the polymorphic relation.)

Question:  How do I make a scope, that returns records based on the *absence* of entries in another class pointing back at the class in question.

The current code does not work because the relation pointer is in the records_invalidations table, not the records table.

**UPDATE 2**

The record_invalidation class matches the table name just fine, I think the problem is the column name.  Here's the (simplified) schema:

```
create_table "records", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "content",        null: false
end

create_table "record_invalidations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "archivable_id"
  t.string   "archivable_type"
end
```

**UPDATE 3**

I see know why the first error was happening, so I removed that update.
Now I am passing the correct table name that I am joining in the SQL query, but I have a number of arguments mismatch.  Can I pass another argument to the where clause?

```
self.joins(:invalidation).where('record_invalidations.id is null')
```

Gives:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind 
message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "a56" requires 2

: SELECT  "records".* FROM "records" 
    INNER JOIN "record_invalidations" ON 
    "record_invalidations"."archivable_id" = "records"."id" AND 
    "record_invalidations"."archivable_type" = $1 WHERE 
    (record_invalidations.id is null) AND "plans"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I can't check this at the moment hence the comment, but I think you can do `.joins(:invalidation).where('invalidations.id is null')` or similar, let me know if it works.

Comment: Closer!  I tried:

self.joins(:invalidation).where('invalidations.id is null')

and got a very close SQL output but seeing an error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "invalidation"
LINE 1: ...cord_invalidations"."archivable_type" = $1 WHERE (invalidati...
                                                             ^

Comment: Can you maybe try `self.table_name = 'records'` (or whatever the table name actually is) in the RecordInvalidation class? Maybe the old scope would work - in this case?

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now :) How about `self.joins(:invalidation).where('records.id is null')`, my mistake.

Comment: The last bug is fixed (Yay!) but a new challenger approaches (boo!).

Comment: Okay, the outputted sql is actually an `inner join`, where you need a `left join`, can you change the `joins` to `includes`. I'm not sure where the bind error message is coming from, do you have any idea what is generating this bit: `"plans"."id" = $2` - there's no reference to `plans` in your code (or indeed in the list of tables being selected from).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way, but it works:

```
def self.default_scope
  # Only show records that were not invalidated
  # Makes a list of all invalidated record ids in a subquery then checks for id
  where.not(:id => RecordInvalidation.select(:archivable_id)
                                     .where(archivable_type: self.name)
                                     .uniq)
end
```

Thanks to [rails scope to check if association does NOT exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355002/rails-scope-to-check-if-association-does-not-exist)

I just added the required filtering for the polymorphic association to that answer.

If anyone has a better solution feel free to add and I will accept that instead of my own.