# Active Record - Get records where association doesn't exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `A` which has_many of my `B` model (so the B model references the A with a foreign_key `a_id`).
I would like to get all A records which are not referenced by any B records. Which is the more efficient way to do that with active record?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The detail may depend on your database, indexes you created, and data you store but I'd recommend giving subqueries a try:

```
A.where.not(id: B.select(:a_id))
```

On PostgreSQL this will result in *single query* like:

```
SELECT * FROM as WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT a_id FROM bs)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Gonna accept the answer soon. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, @RonanLopes! If the query turns out to be too slow in your case please post an update and I'm happy to help you tune it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

As of Rails 5:

```
A.left_outer_joins(:bs).where(bs: { a_id: nil })
```

The output of the SQL is:

```
SELECT "as".* FROM "as"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "bs" ON "bs"."a_id" = "a"."id"
WHERE "bs.a_id" IS NULL
```

Comment: Benchmark here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574301/2009803

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that you your models look like

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_may :bs
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
end
```

I am thinking that your schema.rb looks like

```
  create_table "as", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "bs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "id"
    t.integer  "a_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

if I have this right then you should be able to do

```
A.where.not(id: B.select(:a_id))
```